# Lumen provide a code for validation errors

Tags: php, laravel, validation, lumen

Currently in lumen when you use the `$this->validate($request, $rules)` function inside of a controller it will throw a `ValidationException` with error for your validation rules(if any fail of course).

However, I need to have a code for every validation rule. We can set custom messages for rules, but I need to add a unique code.

I know there's a "formatErrorsUsing" function, where you can pass a formatter. But the data returned by the passed argument to it, has already dropped the names of the rules that failed, and replaced them with their messages. I of course don't want to string check the message to determine the code that should go there.

I considered setting the message of all rules to be "CODE|This is the message" and parsing out the code, but this feels like a very hacked solution. There has to be a cleaner way right?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this for now with the following solution:

```
private function ruleToCode($rule) {
    $map = [
        'Required' => 1001,
    ];

    if(isset($map[$rule])) {
        return $map[$rule];
    }

    return $rule;
}

public function formatValidationErrors(Validator $validator) {
    $errors = [];

    foreach($validator->failed() as $field => $failed) {
        foreach($failed as $rule => $params) {
            $errors[] = [
                'code' => $this->ruleToCode($rule),
                'field' => $field,
            ];
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```